# Dataset on donations to charities?

Tags: data-request, data.gov

Is there a feed/database on individuals/companies that have donated to IRS verified charities?

I have done quite some Googling, and cannot seem to find anything :/

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if this is something that is required to be reported.

Data like does this does exist for campaign/PAC contributions and lobbying money spent by corporations. The Sunlight Foundation has a great site called InflueceExplorer.com (which has a web UI, bulk downloads, and API). For example, a search for [Microsoft](http://influenceexplorer.com/organization/microsoft-corp/f1244474fad44ad9a3a57859b4a709b1).

I also heard from a contact well entrenched in the NPO space that major donors might be shown on NPOs' Form 990 that they are required to file with the IRS but I am not seeing it on the sample 990 at http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f990.pdf. You can contact and look at data from 990++ aggregators such as [GuideStar](http://www.guidestar.org/), the [National Center for Charitable Statistics](http://nccs.urban.org/), and [CitizenAudit](https://citizenaudit.org).

**EDIT**: Found this useful FAQ: ["Q: Where can I find out who has donated money to a particular nonprofit organization?"](http://grantspace.org/Tools/Knowledge-Base/Funding-Resources/Individual-Donors/researching-nonprofit-donations). Short answer: "The list of donors filed with Form 990 is specifically excluded from the information available for public inspection, except for donors to private foundations and political organizations."