# Dataset of donations to various medical causes

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a dataset of donations to medical causes, grouped by the cause. In particular, I would like to know whether some medical causes receive more funding than others.

For example, it makes sense that charitable organizations for supporting patients with rare diseases receive less funding than those supporting patients with more common diseases; I want to check if and to what extent this is true.

I found two related but different questions. [This question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3329/2740) requires data about the donors; [this quesiton](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3967/2740) also requires data about the donors and the frequency of donations. in my case, I do not need data about the donors - I need data about the total sum donated to each cause, particularly for causes related to medical issues.